# Append Row During Insert From Select Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm migrating data from a source to destination. A certain mapping specifies that if a field is not null, there is to be an extra record created and inserted into the destination table. My query looks like this so far:

```
select Cast('' as nchar(18)) as Id,
       Cast('' as nvarchar(255)) as Error,
       case
            when a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_TYPE = 'Amount' then 'Amount'
            when a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_TYPE = 'Per Sq. Ft.' then 'Rate/SF'
            end as TI_Input__c,
        case
            when a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_TYPE <> null or a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_TYPE <> '' then 'Cash Allowance'
            end as Improvement_Type__c,
        case
            when a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_TYPE = 'Amount' then a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_AMT
            when a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_TYPE = 'Per Sq. Ft.' then a.CONSTR_CASH_ALWNC_PSF_RATE
            end as Amount_Rate__c,
        case 
            when a.LANDLORD_WORK_EST_CST <> null or a.LANDLORD_WORK_EST_CST <> '' then 
         -- append another row with different values for fields TI_Input__c, 
         -- Improvement_Type__c, Amount_Rate__c to be inserted

-- destination table
into [Migration_DataUpdate].dbo.Tenant_Improvement__c

-- source table
from [SSLE].dbo.Deal_Original_or_Amendment a 
LEFT JOIN [SALESFORCE_LOCAL].dbo.[Opportunity] b on a.[DEAL_ID] = b.Opportunity_Id__c
```

**How would I utilize a case statement to append a row during an insert from a select query?**

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary table for staging your data using two queries:

1. Insert all records from your source table into temporary table
2. Insert the additional records for all of your not null records in your source table into your temporary table

Now that your temporary table has the full set of data, insert everything from your staging table into your destination table.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be an ongoing migration over some period of time and/or noone will be using the new database until after the migration is over, you could consider using a trigger on the table. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Tenant_Improvement_Insert
ON dbo.Tenant_Improvement__c
AFTER INSERT 
  INSERT INTO SecondaryInsertTable (Field1, Field2, ....)
  SELECT FieldA, FieldB, ......
  FROM INSERTED
  WHERE INSERTED.FieldX IS NOT NULL
GO
```

And once your finished with the migration you can disable/drop the trigger.